# Access application error when distributed. My account works fine!!1

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

first time poster here so please be easy on me!

I have searched on here and googled but have found no solution to my problem.

I am using Access 2007 front end application with a MicrosoftSQL back end on a server.

When I distribute the application (created runtime package) to my user (1 other computer on our work network) I cannot use the application with any other windows account except for mine.

I have tried adding other user accounts to the backend with the same permissions as my account but it is still a no go.

Can anyone provide some insight or what else I can try?

Comment: Error messages?

Comment: Are you using windows authentication for SQL server, or are you using SQL logons?